# I have cropped part of the image and want to crop another part of another image with the same size and location

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2014, crop

I'm using Adobe Photoshop CC, and have cropped part of some image, and have saved a `.ps` version of such crop.

I have another image, for which I want to make the crop with exact size and location of the first crop.

How can I go about that in Adobe Photoshop CC?

Answer (score 1):

The tool **Canvas Size** also works for cropping - just make the canvas size smaller -, but requires a bit of fiddling and calculation, to make an arbitrary position cropping possible. First, you'll have to crop so that the anchor is in the top left corner so that:

- width = x position of the crop's top left corner + width of the crop
- height = y position of the crop's top left corner + height of the crop

After that, proceed on to make a second Canvas Size cropping, but now making the bottom right corner as the anchor and the width and height as the desired final size.

Another way is to use the normal **Rectangular Marquee Tool** and select *Style: Fixed Size* from the options panel (the one located by default under the menu bar) and setting the desired crop size. Now just position the marquee by holding on the mouse and adjusting it to the exact same position by reading the hover notification coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your cropped Image (IMAGE A) and open other Image (IMAGE B) which you want to Crop by opening both files, Drag IMAGE B to IMAGE A File By Pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> Key. It will take exact position(location), size and resolutions. Merged it By <kbd>CTR + E</kbd> and save as new PSD file.

For more help watch this [Video](http://youtu.be/DX5Kl5czQuI)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I'm kind of new to photoshop. When I open both images, I get like two tabs at the top of the window representing each image. Is this the correct way when you mentioned to open both images? Regarding dragging IMAGEB to IMAGEA, how should I do that? If from the tabs above, the tabs only get moved. And, for the image inside the window, I couldn't drag it anywhere. Appreciate your kind support

Comment: just watch this video for more help http://youtu.be/DX5Kl5czQuI